# When to use PHAsset, PHCollection, PHAssetCollection, and PHCollectionList

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

I want to extract all photo albums from an iPhone. I am confused when to use and how to use

> PHAsset, PHCollection, PHAssetCollection, and PHCollectionList

using objective C and the procedure to get all the album list with the photos.

Any help would be appreciated as I am entirely new to iOS.

Comment: Start by looking at the sample app that Apple provides that makes use of the Photos framework.

Comment: SO isn't a great place for open-ended questions. Have you read the [documentation on those classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408)? Or examined the aforementioned sample code? What specifically do you find confusing in those resources? What have you tried, and what problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

Don't fully understand your question but it sounds like you want to display the list of Albums and then on photos within them in the detail screen similar to what Photos app does.

Apple's Sample App demonstrating Photos Framework [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html) can give you a good start on this.